Need way to remove Consume throughput received logger
I am using logstash-pulsar-input plugin in which i can see jar org.apache.pulsar:pulsar-client, 2.11.0 being used and while checking on that found ConsumerStatsRecorderImpl class is printing logs of Consume throughput received.
Is there any way to remove these directly other than improving / building new jar file?
if ((currentNumMsgsReceived | currentNumBytesReceived | currentNumReceiveFailed | currentNumAcksSent |
        currentNumAcksFailed) != 0) {
    log.info(
        "[{}] [{}] [{}] Prefetched messages: {} --- " +
        "Consume throughput received: {} msgs/s --- {} Mbit/s --- " +
        "Ack sent rate: {} ack/s --- " + "Failed messages: {} --- batch messages: {} ---" +
        "Failed acks: {}",
        consumerImpl.getTopic(), consumerImpl.getSubscription(), consumerImpl.consumerName,
        consumerImpl.incomingMessages.size(), THROUGHPUT_FORMAT.format(receivedMsgsRate),
        THROUGHPUT_FORMAT.format(receivedBytesRate * 8 / 1024 / 1024),
        THROUGHPUT_FORMAT.format(currentNumAcksSent / elapsed), currentNumReceiveFailed,
        currentNumBatchReceiveFailed, currentNumAcksFailed);
}


i can try removing all info logs that is one way but dont want to do that
